# Firebase Database reopens activity when a value changes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem in my activity when I change a value in the database. I tried creating a new Activity with a toolbar, the toolbar's title is changed with a database value via `ValueEventListener`. The problem is that when I change the value in my DB, the activity reopens itself.

```
private static String eventKey;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finishAffinity();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeScreenActivity.class));
    }

    eventKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("eventKey");

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Eventos").child(eventKey);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String titleValue = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleValue);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is the full code of the TestingActivity class.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/77Gq3PTR) you can see the previous activity (is too large). And [here](https://pastebin.com/x1MedEnJ) you can see the log when I change something in my DB.

Thanks!

Comment: It changes the title but it also launches another `TestingActivity` activity, am i right?

Comment: Sorry, where do you say it also launches another activity?

Comment: It launches TestingActivity?

Comment: I've put two codes, the one you have here is the TestingActivity.class, and the one in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/77Gq3PTR) is the PrincipalActivity.class. The problem is in TestingActivity. Yes, in the previous activity I launch the TestingActivity and there (in TestingActivity) it changes the title. But it launches only one time that activity. I'm sorry but I don't get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking your code provided in the link, it seems you are launching the `TestingActivity` or `EventSingleActivity`.

This is the code from the link:

```
            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    mDatabase.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String eventTime = dataSnapshot.child("timeStamp").getValue().toString();
                            if(Integer.parseInt(nowTime) > Integer.parseInt(eventTime)){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, TestingActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("eventKey", id);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, EventSingleActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("eventKey", id);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

That's why every changes from the firebase db it will launch the activities I mentioned above.

To fix this you need to do the following:

```
            mDatabase.child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                  String eventTime = dataSnapshot.child("timeStamp").getValue().toString();
                                                if(Integer.parseInt(nowTime) > Integer.parseInt(eventTime)){
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, TestingActivity.class);
                                                    intent.putExtra("eventKey", id);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    finish();
                                                } else {
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, EventSingleActivity.class);
                                                    intent.putExtra("eventKey", id);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                }

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```